# Setting a timeout for mechanize.Browser

Tags: python, timeout, system

I was perusing the question posted here:

[What should I do if socket.setdefaulttimeout() is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464391/what-should-i-do-if-socket-setdefaulttimeout-is-not-working)

to try and come up with a solution to kill requests when my `mechanize.Browser` object is taking too long, and I have been experimenting with the first solution in tomasz's edit (reposted here for clarity):

```
import signal, time

def request(arg):
  """Your http request"""
  time.sleep(2)
  return arg

class Timeout():
  """Timeout class using ALARM signal"""
  class Timeout(Exception): pass

  def __init__(self, sec):
    self.sec = sec

  def __enter__(self):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self.raise_timeout)
    signal.alarm(self.sec)

  def __exit__(self, *args):
    signal.alarm(0) # disable alarm

  def raise_timeout(self, *args):
    raise Timeout.Timeout()

# Run block of code with timeouts
try:
  with Timeout(3):
    print request("Request 1")
  with Timeout(1):
    print request("Request 2")
except Timeout.Timeout:
  print "Timeout"

# Prints "Request 1" and "Timeout"
```

When I run this from my terminal using `python timeout.py` (version is`Python 2.7.2+` and I am on Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot), there is no exception thrown- instead it simply prints

```
Request 1
Request 2
```

Could someone please explain how to fix this?  An explanation of what's going on with those `signal.alarm` and `signal.signal` calls would be awesome too.

Thank you very much for your time!

EDIT:

Running `strace -f python timeout.py` yields:

```
alarm(3)                                = 0
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {2, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb740c000
alarm(0)                                = 1
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x812f450, [], 0}, {0x812f450, [], 0}, 8) = 0
alarm(1)                                = 0
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {2, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
alarm(0)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, {0x812f450, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, {0x812f450, [], 0}, 8) = 0
write(1, "Request 1\nRequest 2\n", 20)  = 20
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Comment: Maybe `sleep` uses `SIGALRM` internally, that is plausible and would mess up your test. Try doing a blocking I/O op instead of sleep (just read from stdin and don't type anything at the console).

Comment: It works for me, same version of Ubuntu. You didn't forget `#!/usr/bin/env python` or `chmod 777 <filename>` did you?

Comment: code works as expected in my environment (cPython 2.6.5 / ubuntu 9.04)

Comment: @johnthexiii No, the result is the same when executed as a shell script like you said.  Thanks guys, hopefully I can resolve this soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what happens here, please try:

```
$ strace -f python timeout.py
```

For me (running Debian 6 with python 2.6) this works. strace output of the important part:

```
alarm(3)                                = 0
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {2, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 15), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) =  x7f0fbbe06000
write(1, "Request 1\n", 10Request 1)             = 10
alarm(0)                                = 1
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x4d0a90, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f0fbb9deff0}, {0x4d0a90, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f0fbb9deff0}, 8) = 0
alarm(1)                                = 0
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {2, 0})     = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted)
--- SIGALRM (Alarm clock) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigreturn(0xffffffff)                = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
alarm(0)                                = 0
write(1, "Timeout\n", 8Timeout
)                = 8
```

alarm(3) is called; Request 1 comes through; alarm(1) is called which gives a Timeout.

Comment: I have posted the output of my `strace` in an edit.  I'm really confused why this won't work for me, but will for other people- seems in my `strace` the `write` command only is called once, and the exception never gets thrown.  Any ideas?  Thanks.