# How to set timeout with python-mechanize?

Tags: python, timeout, mechanize-python

I'm using [python-mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to scrape some web sites, which sometime simply don't respond to requests and these requests stay open too long, so I need to limit timeout for these requests.

While using `urlopen` method, the timeout can be set using `timeout` parameter, but I have not found easy way for doing it with high level API such as `submit` or `click` methods. Ideally the timeout would be set just once for whole browser class and all calls would honor that.

It would be probably possible to customize this by passing custom `request_class` to every `click` and `submit` call, but this would just pollute the code, so I'm looking for nicer solution for setting timeout for mechanize's browser class (and no, I don't want to change default socket timeout using `socket.setdefaulttimeout`).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464391/what-should-i-do-if-socket-setdefaulttimeout-is-not-working

Comment: I know that mechanize.Request can specify timeout. The problem is that I'm not using Request class directly, but through mechanize's click or submit methods, which don't expose way to set a timeout.

Comment: `Browser.__init__`  takes `request_class` isn't that used as default?

Comment: Unfortunately this one is not passed to click/submit methods, they have their own hardcoded default.

Answer (score 2):

It is slightly frowned upon within the Python community, but you can "duck punch" the desired behaviour into the browser class.

Basically, you need to do the following. Create a function that does what you want (using a custom request class).

```
browser_click = Browser.click
def my_click(self, *args, **kwds):
    browser_click(self, request_class=MyRequestClass, *args, **kwds)
Browser.click = my_click
```

If that is too Ruby for your taste, you can create a subclass of Browser that does something similar.

```
class MyBrowser(Browser):
    def click(self, *args, **kwds):
        Browser.click(self, request_class=MyRequestClass, *args, **kwds)
```

This I find a bit cleaner, but it will not work in case you have no control the creation of your Browser instances.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a do-while loop with code such as:

```
start = time.clock()
... do something
elapsed = (time.clock() - start)
```

or

```
start = time.time()
... do something
elapsed = (time.time() - start)
```