# How to wait less for connection timeout in Python3 requests?

Tags: python, exception, timeout, python-requests

I have something like this for requests error exception:

```
try:
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    print("HTTP exception error: {}".format(err))
    return
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print("Exception error {}".format(e))
    return
```

To get an error like this I have to wait more than 2 minutes:

> Exception error HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.137.67', port=8000):
>   Max retries exceeded with url: /python-3.4.3.msi (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110]
>   Connection timed out',))

Is it possible to faster get timeout error? Try one or two times and then continue if something is wrong?

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`timeout` paramater:

```
r = requests.get(url, stream=True, timeout=10)
```

This will raise an exception if the request takes up than `10 seconds`

[More informations.](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts)

Comment: `timeout=10` will raise an error if the connection goes for more than 10 seconds without transferring any data. If a connection makes a little bit of progress every 5 seconds it might still take a request several minutes to complete. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8465202/456550) for an explanation and for some examples of how to set a timeout for the entire request.